# When to use single or double quotes in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query

```
select * 
from sysobjects
where type = "U"
```

and the result is exactly the same as

```
select * 
from sysobjects 
where type = 'U'
```

So I wonder what is the difference between the single quotes `'` and double quotes `"`?

Comment: Simple, in SQL Server just always use single quotes for text data, and always use `[...]` to quote the *names* of SQL objects (tables, columns, etc.).  You should never need (nor use, IMHO) double quotes.

Comment: If you use [`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) you can use `where type = "U"` by default this will throw an error "invalid column name 'U'". MSDN: _"When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON (default) all strings delimited by double quotation marks are interpreted as object identifiers....."_